# Single Line IF in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2

In C# we can write single if syntax:

```
string test;
int value=1;
test = value>=1 ? "is bigger or equal one" : "is less than one";
```

T-SQL in SQL Server 2008 R2 has single `IF` syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @value INT = 1;

SET @test = CASE WHEN @value >= 1 THEN 'is bigger or equal one' ELSE 'is less than one' END
```

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't, you'd have to use a CASE statement...

SQL Server 2012 does have the function:

```
SELECT IIF ( @FirstArgument > @SecondArgument , 'TRUE', 'FALSE' ) 
 AS [Output Using IIF Logical Function]
```